# Split Editor: Go to Definition opens a new tab in the current split even if the target is already open in another split

Tags: visual-studio-code

- VSCode Version: 1.8.1
- OS Version: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Split Editor
2. Open `source1.js` with a function definition in the first split
3. Open `unrelated.js` in the first split
4. The active tab in the first split is `unrelated.js`
5. Open `source2.js` calling the function in the second split
6. From the second split ctrl+click on the function name
7. `source1.js` is opened again in the second split

I would like to jump to the `source1.js` opened in the first split.

Note: if `source1.js` is the active tab in the first split it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/7432) I have found the solution: set `"workbench.editor.revealIfOpen": true` in user/workspace settings. By default its value is `false`.

Description for this setting:

> Controls if an editor is revealed in any of the visible groups if
>   opened. If disabled, an editor will prefer to open in the currently
>   active editor group. If enabled, an already opened editor will be
>   revealed instead of opened again in the currently active editor group.
>   Note that there are some cases where this setting is ignored, e.g.
>   when forcing an editor to open in a specific group or to the side of
>   the currently active group.

Comment: Thanks for following up on this relatively old question. I tested the flag and indeed it works.